# Ruby github client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, github-api

I want to get Json data from [Github resume](http://resume.github.io/?ryanb), of the user who login's into my website using "Omniauth-Github".

I used [github_api](http://rubygems.org/gems/github_api), but could not find any method for it.

Can anyone help me with gem or how can I do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not directly accessible through the Github API - sorry. You can get at all of the information used to hydrate the cv easily enough though. It might require a few pings back and forth though so you will want to cache the hell out of the results.